# Grayscale image not saving using BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY

Tags: java, bufferedimage, kinect-v2

I am trying to save a depth map from Kinect v2 which should come out as grayscale but every time that I try to save it as JPG file using the type `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY` literally nothing happens (No warning on screen or in the console).

I manage to save it if I use types `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB` or `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB` but instead of being grayscale it come as out blueish or greenish depth maps.

Find below the code sample:

```
short[] depth = myKinect.getDepthFrame();
int DHeight=424;
int DWidth = 512;
int dx=0;
int dy = 21;

BufferedImage bufferDepth = new BufferedImage(DWidth,  DHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);

try {
    ImageIO.write(bufferDepth, "jpg", outputFileD);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong to save it in grayscale?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think the standard `ImageIO` JPEG plugin supports writing 16 bit (USHORT) samples. Note that `ImageIO.write(...)` returns a `boolean`. If the return value is `false`, then nothing is written. You should check this value, to get feedback for why nothing happens. The easiest fix would probably be to use a different format, one that supports 16 bit samples, like TIFF or PNG.

Comment: PS: Even if the image was written correctly, the above code would not store the depth map, as there's simply no interaction between `depth` and `bufferDepth`. You probably have this in your real code, but it would make the problem clearer if you added it to the code sample.

Comment: @HaraldK, Yes you are right it does return a false boolean value, is there anay alternative to ImageIO.write(...) ?

Comment: @HalraldK, TIFF does not give results but PNG return a a very dark depth map

Comment: Yes, given the above code, I would expect the image to be completely black (as already noted). A (now deleted) answer mentioned the range of values from Kinect using only 14 (?) bits. You either need to scale the values, or create the image with the correct range.

Comment: I think it uses 16 bits myself, I do not know where this 14 bits business is coming from. What do you mean by scaling the value? Do you mean the same way it is done below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign your data (depth) to the BufferedImage (bufferDepth) first.

A simple way to do this is:

```
short[] depth = myKinect.getDepthFrame();
int DHeight = 424;
int DWidth = 512;
int dx = 0;
int dy = 21;

BufferedImage bufferDepth = new BufferedImage(DWidth, DHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);

for (int j = 0; j < DHeight; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DWidth; i++) {
        int index = i + j * DWidth;
        short value = depth[index];
        Color color = new Color(value, value, value);
        bufferDepth.setRGB(i, j, color.getRGB());
    }
}

try {
    ImageIO.write(bufferDepth, "jpg", outputFileD);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yuri, I got an error running your code coming from the fact that the values of value are too big (should be maximum 255)

Comment: I have no idea what are the values in depth[], I was assuming that the values range from 0 to 255. But you can surely normalize those values. If you do know what is the maximum value you can do a simple math:

short value = (depth[index] * 255) / maxValue;